# I would like my second Exchange account to notify me of emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange, forwarding

[Forwarding options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otf9w.png)

I have an Exchange email account at one of my clients, where I can log on with a Citrix connection. I log on to the mail server on a Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 Outlook client.

I have no mobile device access to the email account. Therefore, in order to make sure I get emails sent to my account at the client's, I would like Exchange to notify me that there is an email. But I don't want Exchange to forward the email since the client has a policy against autoforwarding everything to external email servers. Also I don't want the senders to notice that emails are causing notifications to my other account.

But all the options for creating a rule in Exchange are either a forward or a reply (see picture). That means, either I autoforward the content to another email server, breaking my client's rules, or I reply (and CC myself) to the sender, meaning everyone sending an email to me gets a strange auto-reply every time they mail me.

The option "Generate incident report and send it to..." might appear to be a possibility, but as it turns out, it only allows the incident report to be sent to internal accounts. So that doesn't seem to be a possibility.

I would like to create a rule that just sends a notification email to my other (external) email account, saying for example "You have a new message at your client's account", without notifying the original sender that their email has caused a notification to my other email account.

Is there any clever way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a notification related with these specific messages to your second email address, you could try creating the following rules:

1. **Tranpsort Rule** which will send a notification to your primary mailbox

[image]

2. **Inbox(Outlook) rule** which will redirect the notification in the first rule to your second email address

**Note:** This rule will move these notification messages to a specifc folder in your primary mailbox, if you want to do that, you need specify a default folder or create a new subfolder.

[image]

Of course, you could continue to add some conditions to the two rules to narrow down the scope of filtering.

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan_Wang! I was maybe hoping to take care of this without having the client's admins involved, but actually it is a good idea to ask them to create this rule. And then as you point out, I can take care of the rest in Outlook. Thanks!